# LIBSVM Accuacy change everytime for the same method?

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm

Im using LIBSVM to do classification.
I had extracted the SIFT features and then I train OVRTRAIN and OVRPREDICT of my features.

Before that, i did cross validation using  this code:

```
  bestcv = 0;
  for log2c = -1:1:3,
  for log2g = -4:1:2,
   cmd = ['-q -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g)];
   cv = get_cv_ac(label_Train_sift, Feat_Train, cmd, 3);
   if (cv >= bestcv),
    bestcv = cv; bestc = 2^log2c; bestg = 2^log2g;
    end
   fprintf('%g %g %g (best c=%g, g=%g, rate=%g)\n', log2c, log2g, cv, bestc, bestg,   
   bestcv);
   end 
   end
```

And training (to get the model and accuracy):

```
 bestParam = ['-t 0 -c ', num2str(bestc), ' -g ', num2str(bestg)];
 model = ovrtrain(label_Train_sift, Feat_Train, bestParam);
 [predict_label, accuracy, prob_values] = ovrpredict(label_Test_sift, Feat_Test, model);
```

But I have to train with many different features and Parameter.. For example for 1st training, Im using SIFT with Hesian method and then DoG method, etc etc.

When I already tried all of that method and for example I got HESIAN as the best method (which gives good accuracy among the others), BUT when I train again the same features with the Hessian Method (withoud any change).. The accuracy become different..

How it can be??

Is it because of the Cross Validation??
But when I tried for the 4th time, I go the same accuracy, but the 2nd and 3rd is different..

For the 1st training, accuracy 67
2nd, accuracy 55
3rd, accuracy 45
???

why??